# can't return float value from function

Tags: 1-wire, functions

I want to put a 2 seconds delay to temperature reading but the `millis()` delay is not applying.

```cpp
#include <OneWire.h>
#include <LiquidCrystal_I2C.h>
#include <DS3231.h>
#include <DallasTemperature.h>

#define ONE_WIRE_BUS 2

Time t;
LiquidCrystal_I2C lcd(0x27, 16, 2);
DS3231  rtc(SDA, SCL);
OneWire oneWire(ONE_WIRE_BUS);
DallasTemperature sensors(&oneWire);

const int OnHour = 23;
const int OnMin = 42;
const int checkTemp = 2000;
const int checkTempinterval = 0;

void setup() {
  Serial.begin(115200);
  pinMode(3, OUTPUT);
  lcd.begin();
  lcd.backlight();
  rtc.begin();
}
void loop() {
  t = rtc.getTime();
  float testTemp;
  testTemp = temperature();
  lcd.setCursor(0,0);
  lcd.print(testTemp);
  lcd.print("   ");
  lcd.print(rtc.getTimeStr());
  lcd.setCursor(0,1);
  lcd.print(rtc.getDOWStr());
  lcd.print("   ");
  lcd.print(rtc.getDateStr());
  if(testTemp >= 28){
    digitalWrite(3,HIGH);
  }else{
    digitalWrite(3,LOW);
  }
//  if(t.hour == OnHour && t.min == OnMin){
//    digitalWrite(3,HIGH);
//  }else{
//    digitalWrite(3,LOW);
//  }
}
float temperature(){
  unsigned long currenttime = millis();
  if(currenttime - checkTempinterval >= checkTemp){
  sensors.requestTemperatures();
  float testTemp = sensors.getTempCByIndex(0);
  currenttime = checkTempinterval;
  return testTemp;
  }
}
```

Comment: First of all, not all execution paths are returning the value, second of all, why are you doing: `currenttime = checkTempinterval;`, it's pointless as it won't exist anymore after the return.

Comment: There is nothing called "minis" in your code example.

Comment: @KIIV so i can't return value from sensors.getTempCByIndex(0);? it's reading the temp but the delay is not applying...

Comment: You can, but code is not doing it in case the if condition fails.

Comment: @KIIV so what's the solution?

Comment: Delete it all, and start from a scratch. Enable all warnings! Don't use any branches in temperature(), maybe even forget about functions, until you don't understand concept of local variables and it's scope and existence. Just use delay(2000), read rtc, request temperature, print results

Comment: that's a question and by kindly answering it you can help me to "understand the concept of local variables" and i don't want to use delay!

Comment: Also asked here: https://forum.arduino.cc/index.php?topic=621590.0

Comment: @Jot "Detective achievement unlocked"!

Comment: Moreover what is the question?  I don't see one.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I see 2 problems with your code:

1. **Returning a value from a function:** If you want to return a value from a function, you will have to make sure, that in any case the `return x` statement is executed inside the function in the `temperature()` function you currently have this if statement:

   ```
   if(currenttime - checkTempinterval >= checkTemp){
   ```

   Inside of it is the only `return` statement. That means, if the function is called before the next measurement time, the function will not return anything. Normally the compiler gives you at least a warning about that (maybe you have to turn the warnings on in the settings of the Arduino IDE).

   Here you also have to think about, what you want to return, if no measurement was actually executed. Do you want to return an error value (for example `-300`; the error value should not be found inside valid data)? Then do so after the `if` statement. Or do you want it to simply return the last measured value? Then declare a variable (either at global scope, meaning outside of any function, or at local scope, meaning inside the function, but static, which means that the value will be retained between the functions executions). Save the measured temperatures to this variable and return it after the `if` statement.

   If you do this, also consider what that means for the rest of your code. For example, if you return an error value, currently it will also be displayed by your code.
2. **Doing the `millis()` code correctly:** What you are doing wrong here, it that you update the wrong variable inside the `if` statement. Currently you write the value of `checkTempinterval` (which is the time of the last measurement) to the variable `currenttime`. The variable `currenttime` was declared locally (meaning inside the function) by using

   ```
   unsigned long currenttime = millis();
   ```

   Local variables are only present during the execution of the function, that they are declared in. When the microcontroller has executed the `return` statement, it will throw all local variables away, making the RAM free for other variables. That means currently you are saving a value inside a variable, that get's thrown away directly after it.

   What you actually meant to do, was to do it vice versa:

   ```
   checkTempinterval = currenttime;
   ```

   `checkTempinterval` is a global variable. It will stay in RAM during the whole program execution. Since it holds the last measurement time, you write the currenttime to it, when you measure.

   **Very important:** Currently `checkTempinterval` is defined as `const int` meaning constant integer. This variable must not be constant, since we want to change the value (update the time of the last measurement). Also you should not use `int` here, because it's value range goes only up to 32767, which is 32 seconds when used with `millis()`. After that, it will overflow to negative values. Better use the type of `millis()` return value: `unsigned long`. It has 4 byte (instead of `int`s 2 byte) and will only overflow after 49 days. If you only use this variable type for things with `millis()`, even this overflow will not be a problem.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `millis()` function to create a "timer" that will get the sensor reading every 2 seconds. The sketch `BlinkWithoutDelay.ino`, should come with the Arduino IDE, but if not, you can find it here: [BlinkWithoutDelay](https://www.arduino.cc/en/Tutorial/BlinkWithoutDelay).

I've used that exact sketch with some modifications to display the results on the Serial Monitor instead of blinking an LED. When you are creating something, using the Serial Monitor can help you to De-bug your sketch.

Please read the code comments in the following sketch. Once you have this working with your code, then you could decide if you need a function or not.

```cpp
// Store the last time you checked the sensor.
unsigned long previousMillis = 0;

// interval at which to checked the sensor (milliseconds)
const long interval = 2000;

void setup() {
  Serial.begin(9600);
}

void loop() {
  // here is where you'd put code that needs to be running all the time.

  // Get the current time.
  unsigned long currentMillis = millis();

  // Check to see if it's time to check the sensor reading.
  if (currentMillis - previousMillis >= interval) {
    // save the last time you checked the sensor.
    previousMillis = currentMillis;

    // This is where you add the code that checks the sensor.

    // Test output.
    Serial.println("Checking Sensor");
  }
}
```